# How do I get Information from log file's last modified using Python?

Tags: python, information-retrieval, last-modified

I am new to Python and I am trying to create a script to go through all of my daily log files to check for errors.

I can open the files, print the last time the log file was modified, and print out any errors in the log file.

However, these logs have daily information for the past three years in them.  I want to be able to only read the section of the log from the last modified date of the log (Instead of getting all errors from the past three years, I only want the error from the last day.)

Here is what I have for my script so far:

```
import sys, string, os, time

from stat import *

from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()

f3 = 'C:\Path\filename.txt'

seconds = os.path.getmtime(f3)
print "Last Date Ran: ", time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S' , time.localtime(seconds))

for line in open(f3 , 'r'):
    if 'error' in line:
        print ">>> " , line
    elif 'Error' in line:
        print ">>> " , line
    elif 'ERROR' in line:
        print ">>> " , line
```

Is there any way to do this?  I have searched high and low and not found an answer to my problem.  Please help.

Comment: Do your logged errors have time stamps?

Comment: Are you sure you want last modified time?  Isn't that going to always give you only the last message logged to the file?

Comment: just FYI, there is a logging module in python. Worth checking that out if you didn't know it existed

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, no.  Longer answer is that you'd have to either have lots of wasteful parsing or track some data externally to the file.  You can loop over the entire file, parse the timestamp of the log message, then only print those after a given time.  Though for a file with 3 years of data, you'd probably be better off keeping track of the last line your script read then seeking to that line each time you open the file to parse it daily.  Another alternative, if you have access to the relevant pieces in the process, would be to modify the logging mechanism; you could duplicate the messages to a second file that you flush every time your script runs, or basically buffer the logging through a second file and make it the responsibility of your script to archive the logs to the historical file.

Comment: Agree, have a daily logger, check messages with your script, and re-log messages to a historical file once you have done what you've needed with the log messages.

Answer (score 0):

It would be could if you'd supply some more information, e.g., format of you log-files.

Look at the method `datetime.datetime.strptime`. There you'll find all you need.

E.g.

```
import os.path
from datetime import datetime

filename = "my.log"

def log_entry_is_interesting(line, reference_time):
    date_str = line.split()[0]
    date = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    return timedelta(current_datetime, date).days > reference_time:


last_time_opened = os.path.getmtime(filename)
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in filter(lambda x: log_entry_is_interesting(x, last_time_opened), f):
        do_something()
```

I use the `filter()`-method. This is implemented as generator in Python 3, but not in Python 2.x. If you use 2.x, I'd definitely use `ifilter` from the `itertools`-module.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get errors from last time you run the script, try storing last read position of the log file in an another file, and seek to that position when reading log file next time.

Answer (score 0):

If lines in the file are sorted by date (it would be reasonable for a append-only log) then you could you could read the file in reverse order ([`tac` utility](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tac) - find or implement Python version if it is not available on your system) and stop reading if the date is too far in the past:

```
# ..
if 'error' in line.lower():
   if getdate(line) < today:
      break # stop processing
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use seek function to reach to the end of file and find out last date by searching for new line character or otherwise. Once found, you can proceed accordingly. I had written below script to find out last date from each file. This function first 
This function finds date of last entry in the given log file. To find that it starts from the end of file and keep going 2 characters back and checks if the next character is new line character. When there is a new line character, it reads the first 10 characters. However, when there are exceptions from other services in logs, the beginning of line may not contain date stamp. Hence we use try except loop to iterate further back in case last line does not contain date stamp.

```
list= glob.glob("DebugLogFile.log*")

start_time = time.time()


def end_date(file):
count=0;
with open(file, "rb") as f:
    first = f.readline()
    # Read the first line.
    `enter code here`f.seek(-2, os.SEEK_END)
    #print f.tell()  # Jump to the second last byte.
    #print f.read(1)
    flag=True;
    while (flag) :
        try :
            #print f.tell()
            f.seek(-2, os.SEEK_CUR)
            while f.read(1) != b"\n": # Until EOL is found...
                try:
                    f.seek(-2, os.SEEK_CUR)
                    #print f.tell()             
                except:
                    f.seek(0,os.SEEK_SET)
                    print "test"
                    break

            #Remembering the current pointer in case we have to re-evaluate the date in case of exception
            last_pos = f.tell()
            last = f.readline() 
            date=last[:10]
            datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
            flag=False
            return datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()

        except Exception, err_msg:

            f.seek(last_pos)





def threshold(file):
base_date=end_date(file)
print("Base date is ", base_date)
print("Computing the threshold.......")
#convert the string to date object
#base_date_ob=datetime.datetime.strptime(base_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
threshold=base_date-timedelta(days=14)
return threshold

if __name__ == "__main__":
thresh=threshold("DebugLogFile.log")
print thresh

#list =['DebugLogFile.log.100']
#print list
for file in list :
    tmp=end_date(file)
    if(tmp>=thresh):

        print ("Process file :", file, "Which has end date as ", tmp)
    else:
        print ("Do Not Process file :", file, "Which has end date as ", tmp)
time=time.time()
```